# Sophisticated Prose: Good or Bad?

Tags: style, clarity, rhythm

Prose that was written in earlier times has more complex sentences than prose that is written today, sentences whose meaning is not so easy for modern readers to grasp, because their complexity burdens these readers’ memories. But I want to compose those kinds of sentences, liking that manner of writing, thinking it necessary to write in that manner in order to author prose with the rhythm I want.

So what should I do?

Comment: Is it really true that sophistication = burden on memory?

Comment: Sophisticated prose, the kind which was written in earlier times, having longer phrases and phrases parenthetical, place a burden on the memories of readers in this period, a truth which is clearly seen in this fact, that not only linguists declare it themselves, but also many, from this modern time, refuse to read prose written in earlier ages.

Comment: In light of these things, please reverse the downvotes. Thank you.

Comment: This question should not have been closed, as it pertains not to what I should write but to how I should write.

Comment: I'm not sure why you've used this question as a space to test your redrafting skills. And when I first saw it, it actually had a question, to which my answer would have been that you should write whatever you like, unless your livelihood depends on selling your work. I'd also (quite seriously) like to hear the reasoning behind your artistic decision to retain the present tense in the phrase, 'Prose that is written in earlier times'.

Comment: Sorry. 1. I wasn't satisfied with the way my post sounded.  I'm still not satisfied with it. 2. I readded the question. 3. I retained the present tense in the phrase you mentioned because I failed to pay attention to what I was doing.

Comment: Learn Greek or Latin to learn language at a fundamental level. Complex sentences don’t arise out of nothing, they arise out of the authors understanding of language: grammar at the fundament. I say those languages because they provide the foundation of grammar used with Indo European languages. It works.

Answer (score 3):

### Simplicity is better

It is inherently better to write in the simplest possible manner required to communicate your ideas.

As someone who reads a lot of older prose (I recently finished McCauley's History of England), I'm definitely aware of the differences you tend to see in older works.  The most extreme example I can recall was some years ago as I struggled with The Federalist Papers, having to go back and reread half a page three times, because I kept losing track of the subject in one long, run-on sentence.  It was worth it to parse out what the author was saying, but what a chore.

While it is true that there are deep, profound ideas sometimes embedded in a poorly-written sentence or paragraph, it's faulty reasoning to suppose that it is the more arcane or difficult language that makes it better.  To have a profound idea combined with clear, concise prose is better than to have only one without the other.  This doesn't mean that all writing that is complex is bad; in exactly the same way that an elegant solution to a sophisticated Calculus problem cannot be expressed in simple arithmetic (and would be longer and more confusing  if it was!), you cannot always reduce a sophisticated idea to a single, straightforward sentence.

Don't let the notion that some ideas can only be captured by complex statements act as an excuse to be lazy, though.  Yes, lazy.  If you can say something in a few simple words and still capture the heart and soul of your idea, you've "solved" communication more elegantly than if it takes you paragraphs of obscure vocabulary and extra clauses to hammer it out.

It may take longer to craft an elegant, pithy remark that encapsulates everything.  But simplicity is better.

Comment: I upvoted your answer out of respect for your opinion, and in honor of the quality of your insight.

Comment: And I upvoted your answer because it's good.